# Why ajax response is replacing all html content in ajax call?

Tags: jquery

I am working for a small project.
But my code is not working.
When I call function,the ajax response replace all element
.
I have tried with jquery append,prepend,before and after but nothing happen.
Any ideas about how i can fix this? Thanks in advance.

Here is my demo code

```
        <div class="post"id="1">  
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quidem distinctio, dolores soluta, exercitationem nam obcaecati adipisci quasi tempore tempora voluptatum.</p> 
    </div>
    <div class="post"id="2">  

      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quidem distinctio, dolores soluta, exercitationem nam obcaecati adipisci quasi tempore tempora voluptatum.</p> 
    </div>
    <div class="post"id="3">  
      <div>Total Li</div>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quidem distinctio, dolores soluta, exercitationem nam obcaecati adipisci quasi tempore tempora voluptatum.</p> 
    </div>
    <div class="post"id="4">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quidem distinctio, dolores soluta, exercitationem nam obcaecati adipisci quasi tempore tempora voluptatum.</p> 
    </div>
    <div class="post"id="5">  
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quidem distinctio, dolores soluta, exercitationem nam obcaecati adipisci quasi tempore tempora voluptatum.</p> 
    </div>


Js code
           
             get_likes();
      function get_likes(){
        $('.post').each(function(){
          let post_id=$(this).attr('id');
          let element=$(this,'p');
          $.ajax({
            url:'total_likes.php',
            type:'post',
            data:{
              'post_id':post_id
            },
            success:function(data){
              $(element).html("Total likes "+data);
            }
          });
        })
      }

    PHP code
       if(isset($_POST['post_id'])){
      include 'conn.php';
      $post_id=$_POST['post_id'];
      $sql5 = "SELECT * FROM `post_record` WHERE `id_post` = :post_id";
      $stmt5=$conn->prepare($sql5);
      $stmt5->bindparam(':post_id',$post_id);
      $stmt5->execute();
      while($row5 = $stmt5->fetch()){
echo $row['total_likes'];
           }
            ?>

       Database structure
      -Table name:post_record
      -Indexes:
              -id
              -post_id
               -total_likes
```

Comment: Probably `let element=$('p', this);` is what you're looking for (Select the `p` tag/s inside the element)

Comment: Yes but it replace all content inside div...

Comment: OK so what _do_ you want it to do?

Comment: I want to display each post likes in p tag

Comment: change element like this `$("#"+post_id).html("Total likes "+data);`

Comment: Will it work...?

Comment: Please can you try this code for me...?

Comment: Please try this for me...

Comment: Yes. it should works.

Comment: Not working....

Answer (score 1):

I modified your Ajax call a little bit and connected it with some test data from typicode.com. This should demonstrate how you could append an extra `<p>` to each `<div>` with class="post":

```js
$(".post").each(function(i,po){
  $.ajax({
        url:'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/'+po.id,
        type:'get',
        dataType:"JSON",
        success:function(data){
          $(po).append("<p>Total likes: "+data.name.charCodeAt(0)+"</p>");
        }
      })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
<div class="post"id="1">  
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quidem distinctio, dolores soluta, exercitationem nam obcaecati adipisci quasi tempore tempora voluptatum.</p> 
</div>
<div class="post"id="2">  

  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quidem distinctio, dolores soluta, exercitationem nam obcaecati adipisci quasi tempore tempora voluptatum.</p> 
</div>
<div class="post"id="3">  
  <div>Total Li</div>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quidem distinctio, dolores soluta, exercitationem nam obcaecati adipisci quasi tempore tempora voluptatum.</p> 
</div>
<div class="post"id="4">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quidem distinctio, dolores soluta, exercitationem nam obcaecati adipisci quasi tempore tempora voluptatum.</p> 
</div>
<div class="post"id="5">  
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quidem distinctio, dolores soluta, exercitationem nam obcaecati adipisci quasi tempore tempora voluptatum.</p> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.

```
get_likes();

function get_likes(){
    $('.post').each(function(){
        let post_id=$(this).attr('id');
        let element=$(this,'p');
        $.ajax({
            url:'total_likes.php',
            type:'post',
            data:{'post_id':post_id},
            success:function(data){
                $("#"+post_id).html("Total likes "+data);
            }
        });
    })
}
```